# In Vim, what is the opposite of ctrl+w ctrl+w?

Tags: vim, editor

`ctrl+w ctrl+w` cycles through the viewports, but how do I go in the reverse direction?

Suppose I have 3 buffers open in a vsplit, repeatedly doing `ctrl+w ctrl+w` would go 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, ... What about if I want to go 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, ...

```
_____________________________________________________________
|                   |                   |                   |
|                   |                   |                   |
|                   |                   |                   |
|         1         |         2         |         3         |
|                   |                   |                   |
|                   |                   |                   |
|                   |                   |                   |
|                   |                   |                   |
```

Comment: `hjkl` are valid after `ctrl+w` to move in any direction. You can even throw a number in (like `ctrl+w 3 l`) to move by more than one window.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's try the `:help CTRL-W_CTRL-W`:

> ```
> CTRL-W w
> CTRL-W CTRL-W   Without count: move cursor to window below/right of the
>                 current one.  If there is no window below or right, go to
> ```

Now just read on...

> ```
> CTRL-W W        Without count: move cursor to window above/left of current
>                 one.  If there is no window above or left, go to bottom-right
> ```

Though I prefer the "directional" `CTRL-W j` (`k`, `l`, `h`) mappings, especially when mapped to quick `<C-j>` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Move up: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>, <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>

Move down: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>